# Switching back and forth between windows XCode interfaces

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, switching

I am having a very difficult time switching between forms in Cocoa interfaces. From my initial form and its delegate, I can hide the initial window then load and display the second window with all properties on it. This is working working... Alas, on attempting to return to the initial window, I hide the second window and the initial does not return...

Here are my .h and .m for initial form and for formTwo...

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class frmTwoDelegate;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject {
@private
    frmTwoDelegate *_frmTwo;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
- (IBAction)BtnSwitchAction:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "frmTwoDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    ...
}
- (IBAction)BtnSwitchAction:(id)sender {
    if (!_frmTwo) {
        _frmTwo = [[DecriptDelegate alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"frmTwo"];
        [_frmTwo setFrmStart:self];
    }
    [_frmTwo showWindow:sender];
    [_window setIsVisible:NO];
}
@end
```

Here are .h and .m for frmTwo

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class AppDelegate;
@interface frmTwo : NSWindowController{
@private
    AppDelegate *frmStart;
    __unsafe_unretained NSTextView *_TxtView;    
}
@property (retain) AppDelegate *frmStart;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *frmTwo;
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *TxtView;
- (IBAction)BtnOpenActionPreformed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)BtnBackActionPreformed:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "frmTwo.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation frmTwo
@synthesize frmStart;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    ...
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
   ...
}
- (IBAction)BtnOpenActionPreformed:(id)sender 
{
   ...
}
- (IBAction)BtnBackActionPreformed:(id)sender {
    [frmStart ShowWindow];
    [_frmTwo setIsVisible:NO];
}
@end
```

Comment: Before getting an answer, there's a couple problems with the code posted. in BtnBackActionPreformed method, you are referencing _frmTwo, which is not defined anywhere. setIsVisible is also not a method on NSWindow or NSWindowController. So I'm not sure what you are doing there. Additionally it's confusing calling your classes delegates when they inherit NSWindowController. FormTwoController would be a more 'Cocoa' name to call your window controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to achieve what you are doing. I'm not going to write the .h definitions, just infer what the variables represent from their names.

```
- (IBAction)BtnSwitchAction:(id)sender {
    if (!_formTwo) {
        _formTwo = [[DecriptDelegate alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"frmTwo"];
        [_formTwo setFrmStart:self];
    }
    if(_formOne.isVisible) {
        [_window close];
        [_formTwo showWindow:sender];        
    } else if(_formTwo.isVisible) {
        [_formTwo close];
        [_window showWindow:sender];
    }    
}
```

In your nib, make sure both windows have the '`Release when closed`' checkbox unchecked so your window is not released when you call close. In your second FormTwo window controller, you should call the `BtnSwitchAction` from your `BtnBackActionPreformed` method.

I know there's a number of ways you can connect the window switching code to the back button, but I recommend having all the window switching logic in one method on the AppDelegate rather than manipulating OTHER windows from your `BtnBackActionPreformed`. That controller and method shouldn't know about the details of the other windows, it should just tell the AppDelegate to do the switch.